# django htmlmin causing issue in MS Edge

Tags: html, django, microsoft-edge, minify

```
Django==1.11.7
django-htmlmin==0.10.0
django-allauth==0.34.0
```

Django site with django-allauth. New user USING EDGE BROWSER (Microsoft Edge 41.16299.15.0) registers, entering e-mail and password twice. Then press"Register".

Immediately, following info appears within the browser:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: openresty/1.9.15.1 Date: Sun, 14 Jan 2018 18:12:37 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive Vary: Accept-Encoding x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block x-content-type-options: nosniff X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN Content-Language: nl Vary: Accept-Language, Cookie strict-transport-security: max-age=600; includeSubDomains Set-Cookie: messages=""; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/ X-Clacks-Overhead: GNU Terry Pratchett Content-Encoding: gzip 8d2 ‹ÝÛrÛ¸õ½_3³cyG$%Ù’mYÒÔ·´Ùí$Ý¬·Ým&ãIˆ„  ÊR³ù—¾ö7öËz/)É²=ÉSeS&€ƒsÇ¹À£½«w—7¿ýýšD&“~A“pl%Â‚1£Ád3C‰Q¥™[™™Ú'–[MËÄ°¦ß\Y2 0™ÔfŸ2>[¿Ú¿œÛ—2N©áž`›»x`¢qÀfÜgv>hžpÃ©°µOw-’Ð˜­g©T‘n›üüÀ“ðÍ ¹ž§LñR1r‹µ‘àÉ=‰›Ž-×éÜÇ“Òh£hŠ*Æn>ñ@¹‡Î¡sìúLe‚ÑÄ]‚:1X­-¢˜[Ú,ÓcÆ"f‘*†Í‹î3‰NAx›>0-cæ9ÇN·7¦*D4*8žIìPÑù êR É«é þœú÷¡’YØÕÒeþ9#_Fn±¿Ž&¸³›À4’š!ÁÑ‰© y’/ I·“Î·lOèÌ£ 1xŠ& H¥{ÊdH¨§¥È ;#¹¥‡ä¸óÝ)ÐõstŠ‡Ñr€2ÚTð¶ú`\¦*†¤Chf$Ð'QCŠX±{ÐÇÝ%‰bàI0e+ðLï} +gLxCñ` BÍmÑç€ƒü9†G…muÚ¤üuNj„mS!jä{uò½¯$ß”ühÏ¶É9j¿MiÀYàØ)´I¦Y¡¿\£„ 'Ä)ÍZWma[§m.æsùjaµåÊ,+7¨ŸmàØû.À+ª]OA0ñU{ú¥®/n=iŒŒoAÖì–×Þ?zÌ[óNž€òACŸ·ŒþÉù {2GÝ6‰zðÂsOžA›8¸ààŠƒK®9¸èDƒÚé[!Z§[áEpø¢Ã=¢ý<Ø©ô3½ýóã«Aï8§êQÈO ™øÂ'U‹&,L… üƒ' è‡è½ ×Ö«ãÎu§{Ñ&¯Ž//_w»dÐùƒÓóÁÑëƒ¥³W”OO¯×)9ºÉ%cdÇëib–;6¥™0…ìíæõ Ÿ±­“K]ÉÌ (ÛTð•ó¬ë¡b²Â^WÑÚ’LY‚G8P2…‘ØF†¡`l[Ð4Ô°Bµô [Ð”œÇ)8/ àìðíÊdÏr±Bˆh;ôü >§§ˆˆ"¦[ÁÝ*€í>y›GèiÆÝïÉâPx F¦\Œç É%`ùÞ-$«q°Îßâk(¨6¶q éÔÔÅ_emY˜µ@±Iü%„sØ—“/‚GIþiy¨!3 Ü¤–/¾6<6•Šíà§a‹'ùy /(èe]¬(æ›GŒµÛmW'bÓyæH¡ð&žÈ † P¶ëÞÈ RÇro‘èlåà®b“r|F_fg(e>ð)†¼¹&§!]ûŠ§†håc!-µvÊbëglRú:â3¨ÙÞjœWÍwú·@0!»1)¦S™n×9<åhËhïK>ýhÛKÖ|¸$”G<[ÜsË Š•G¨¸Y@iÑ^`_xQ f?MÝùÍo§áí\}:ü+øéõÉßèåû›_çÿúñ=ÅâæèhlŒb ¥‡®ëË€9wŸ2†D~‹W»çô€áM6›²îìyp¢lyîôZ³ÓDê= 'ƒÅd„YÎ'ÖÐæy4ÂâZn,‡S>gDúÐ|‰{@ "ãAs±ÜŠ´™‚%/ƒò/Y[-’©u,  &·¡,±U}/Þæ Õ|¾I ASÍª’³ÀdtJ—D80hã^TÌ£3}ÅòÈ-¨4Ä,J{Ž§kÒåý“UÕÒÖ¤ÙåR@ˆØf\c—½]e’ª={ý‘Jwª•.y0¶– ŸŒ2Qã ‚®½æ­……2[òH_»iæ è4¶÷M´Ë“€Í<çk6 Å"PÕdùfÃÑØoÚzšúQ$¤Õ G}Â“Ñ®!ˆÏ@€vYšý|3V\Qp3Q)î‰³²?Q=€xH‘ýæyðòæ^f)YË6uKÃ©Åþ©š¥G|—|‘Œ Çs•‘çaÇ¼fMÞ³c1œÕ=dj¾£\è,lÈözœ°A±>ØÞzô¬àtž;`ºìOñÎÀšüñŸÇ·q:¶ lE°’œ2$ÿ†@7•Öä‚ÍÐã „š0;¦\€ÿ†\ewº£¾Luðç¤Ä ììÆ«3ßgÐO~Àòš¤$ƒÄ2ð½@ô³6äÝí‡ÿ—¾¶îeÅ BélVeý”¨¶\Å+©Ü êúx`BÙ !`&êUµ”÷O&îeL<~·vOõ`ÇaS¯”`¾0„ßxäÖÒ¿_ê7Ü@åRá‰Ûs»ÖäÍ=:ÁºõêüíÏ×ïÉ“ÍØLÁßâ(Í„X†èZýzîz îÞýrÌÉ)ùÇ»w¹"3ZLcØ‡Rõ1½y 7ÏÃ®Ú¥pŽ¦Í!ïÁÑ²{«Žõ°­c˜Úr_µ#!®å@,þ ö+µçxpBþø/)ïº÷¶f™ÂíËò¯v‹vGg´˜µ&"ð™ >äÖûC}ñdH¦Yâ£iZŸ¡µ0™J 4o“PRñÈâ—³5d·D¼å¬ë3¿ÿN>|,6¬-9i¦£V·Óíœ úÓƒ ¬~¦A‡È©¥!bRÂ{žÿ€µ­Š»ÖŠuò9Ÿ)p#Pedx ¢Ša×‚á¨µ_èj¿ä„í 2aÃþš:÷WT/@ŒÊØjjpÜæ–w ”£…PE¯—Z+f¦äD_,nhødlíc ¼ð¡ó5ù,éìCÓš–Kì5[ t)Ó—ƒVù¶ªðY½¥¯ã2 ÔÎ—9»VyË:¶ºVÕX@‹ÐgiÂD;!ŸZÅå7nqÁ7SôÏ% ·h$ò¦mò?…Ø  0

**When django-htmlmin is disabled, things work fine...**

Also: Other browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) do not face this issue.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you mind providing us with a repro page - also if you file a bug here: bugs.microsoftedge.com with a repro page we can look into it. Thanks.

Comment: I filed a bug at bugs.microsoftedge.com, where you can read how to reproduce this issue. See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/15517742/

Comment: Thanks, I already repro'd it and left some comments - I also passed it onto the correct area owners to investigate.

Comment: I asked this in the bug, but just in case you have the notifications off - have you modified the output at all as I'm no longer able to repro the issue.

Comment: No, I didn't change anything since I submitted the bug report.

In my own environment: when I disable the html minifier, the problem disappears. When I re-enable it, the problem is back.
PS: Cannot comment anymore on the edge bugs site, I get a message "Sorry, we couldn't find that page"

Comment: That's fine we can discuss here or I can send you an email if you'd like, either way we're starting to dig into - but the transient nature of the issue may make this hard to nail down since I repro'd it once and not again.

Comment: The problem is 100% reproducible. Follow the procedure I gave, but each time with a different e-mail address (doesn't need to be an existing one).  Then to reproduce again, press BACK (left arrow on the browser), click "Afmelden" top right, click the button "Afmelden", now start over clicking "registreren" etc. with a different e-mail address and the problem appears again

Comment: New bug submitted on Edge bug reporter as the previous one seems to have disappeared.  New: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/15563187/

Comment: Feedback from Microsoft:  
James M. commented: Hello, Sometimes we archive old cases and it causes some new cases to no longer be visible to the public; we are working to fix that. Please be sure to accept update notifications so you can receive our updates directly to your email.). We are working on the original case. We are presently tracking this issue as a duplicate of existing bug report 15517742. We will update the case when we have more progress. Best Wishes,  The MS Edge Team

Comment: @gregwhitworth: any update? Is this fixed now? In which release? Thx, Davy

Comment: Hey - sorry I had a family emergency come up so haven't had a chance to track this down for ya. I'll interface with the team to see if we can get them a reduction so that the issue can be fixed.

Comment: I can no longer repro this issue - either it was in-advertenly fixed by some other change in the product or the site was changed. This testing on Insider build of 17091.

Comment: I have re-enabled django-htmlmin, and indeed the problem seems fixed now at least in EDGE version 41.16299.248.0  Please confirm.

Comment: I have tested 16 and have now tested 17 and can NOT repro the issue. Thank you for turning it back on so we can see if it repros.

Comment: htmlminifier was already enabled, and is still enabled, so should be able to reproduce it now with the old version